# Does Sprite Kit release Unseen Sprites

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In my Sprite Kit application, I am experiencing a sudden spike in lag after a certain point is reached in the execution. I beleive that I have narrowed the problem area down to the following snippet in my subclass of `SKScene`.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint loc = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    [self addPhysicsBallAtLocation:loc];
    /* included this to show that -addPhysicsBallAtLocation: 
       is being called many times */
}
```

Combined with the following implemetation of the method `-addPhysicsBallAtLocation:`.

```
- (void)addPhysicsBallAtLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
    SKSpriteNode *ball = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWith...]; // just size + color
    /* I add a few properties such as physicsBody to the node. */
    [self addChild:ball];
}
```

As a result of the gravity, the nodes that are created fly off of the screen and are no longer visible. When they leave the screen, the `nodeCount` drops back down to the normal level. Despite the `nodeCount` being where it should be, after a while, the scene will lag out and the frames per second will drop drastically. Once this drop in performance happens, the frames per second never recover and stay at a low 15 fps. So my question is, **What is the root cause of this drop in performance?**

A few things I think might be the cause.

- Sprite Kit does not release sprites after they leave the screen. (Probably this one)
- Unreleased sprites are still being drawn, just off screen. (Might be a factor)
- Calculations for gravity are still being performed after sprite is no longer visible. (Adds to lag)

Comment: as long as a node is part of the scene graph it will not deallocate, Sprite Kit will not remove/release nodes for you unless you use removeFromParent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, as the causes you have listed could be the culprits for the frame drop.

One thing though, unreleased sprites are not drawn at all (the node count on the screen represents the nodes which are being drawn).

In my own project, I have handled a similar situation in the `-update:` method.

For this example, I am assuming that you have set the `name` property of each Ball node as `@"ball"`.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    //Removing ball nodes when they have reached edge of screen
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"ball" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        if (node.position.x < 0 || node.position.x > self.frame.size.width || node.position.y > self.frame.size.height || node.position.y < 0)
        {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }
    }];
}
```